# How to print query result of elasticsearch in python?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Following query gives the vocabulary size of my document in elasticsearch:

```
GET my_index/my_type/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
     "vocab": {
        "cardinality": {
           "field": "text"}}}}
```

The output is:

```
{
"took": 0,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
"total": 1,
"successful": 1,
"failed": 0
},
"hits": {
"total": 84678,
"max_score": 0,
"hits": []
},
"aggregations": {
"vocab": {
"value": 178050**
  }
 }
}
```

Now I want to print the value of the field "value"(=178050) in python.

I wrote the following in python:

```
query_body={
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
     "vocab": {
        "cardinality": {
           "field": "text"}}}}

res = es.search(index = INDEX_NAME, body=query_body)
```

How can I print that value? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your result dictionary looks like this:

```
{
    "took": 0,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 84678,
        "max_score": 0,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "vocab": {
            "value": 178050
        }
    }
}
```

You can access the result like @mohammedyasin recommended:

```
res['aggregations']['vocab']['value']
```

if `res` is a `str`, you can convert it to a dictionary using `json.loads`

```
import json
res = json.loads(s)
value = res['aggregations']['vocab']['value']
```

Comment: Please upvote/mark as answered if the answer helped.

Answer (score 1):

This is you expecting?. 
In python we can get the value from dict by **key**.

from your output:

```
output = {
"took": 0,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
"total": 1,
"successful": 1,
"failed": 0
},
"hits": {
"total": 84678,
"max_score": 0,
"hits": []
},
"aggregations": {
"vocab": {
"value": 178050**
  }
 }
}

print (output["aggregations"]["vocab"]["value"]) # It will print the value or use output.get("aggregations").get("vocab").get("value")
178050
```